# Multiple definition error at the linking stage

Tags: c++

If my projects consist of two translation units *a.cpp* and *b.cpp*, and there is *h.cpp* that have a function **definition**. In this case, each *.cpp* file will be successfully compiled, but we will get multiple definitions at the linking stage. To avoid this (if you don’t put the definition in a separate *.cpp* file), you can make this function

1. **inline**
2. **static**
3. **static inline**
4. **surround it with an empty namespace**

Can someone explain the difference between these four approaches, which is better to use. And what will happen if it is an template function, will there be any problems?

Comment: All options being considered by you are useful in exceptional scenarios when you include header file containing function *definitions*. Usually you keep only *declarations* in headers and include those in cpp files and keep definitions in one of the cpp file or in a separate cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

These are useful explanation of your first 3 declaration:

1. [inline](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inline-functions-cpp/)
2. [static](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/)
3. [static inline](https://gist.github.com/htfy96/50308afc11678d2e3766a36aa60d5f75)

The fourth option is a special case to study in some circumstances.

In case of **Template** you have to remember that all the function have to been defined in the same file, often a `.h` or `.hpp` . If you want to separate definition from implementation remember to include you `.cpp` or the file in which the function are implemented at the end of the file where the function are defined.